# What is the significance of star/link of simplicial complexes

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

I have learnt the definitions of the star and link of simplicial complexes (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex). However, I have not learnt their usefulness yet, beyond the definition.

May I ask what is the significance of them? Do they play an important role, and are there any theorems involving them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One use is to tell if a simplicial complex is a manifold.  If the open stars are homeomorphic to euclidean space, then it is a manifold.  A non-example is that if you do the suspension of a torus, the link of an apex is a torus, so this suspension might not be a manifold.  (Though in fact it isn't a manifold.  This gives an example for why $3$-cycles in homology are not all just represented by $3$-manifolds.)  Unfortunately, this test is not enough to tell whether a simplicial complex *isn't* a manifold, because there are simplicial complexes with non-spherial links which yet are manifolds.

The link is so named because for an algebraic surface in $\mathbb{C}^2$, the link is a [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_(knot_theory)).  As an example, if you take the solutions to $z^2=w^3$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$, which is a two-dimensional surface in four-dimensional space except for a singularity at $(0,0)$, you can examine the link at $(0,0)$.  It is equivalent looking at how the solutions intersect a sphere centered at $(0,0)$, and you'll find the link is actually a trefoil knot in that sphere.

Comment: Actually, this is only a sufficient condition for a simplicial complex to be a manifold. It is *not* a necessary condition, as is shown by the double suspension examples of Cannon and Edwards https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_suspension_theorem

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for the correction --- it appears I believed the Hauptvermutung was true!  If I may summarize your objection, you're saying that there are simplicial complexes which are manifolds but which have non-euclidean stars? (For example, the double suspension of a non-sphere homology sphere.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "non-euclidean stars"; the stars, or their interiors at least, are open subsets of the manifold and hence locally homeomorphic to Euclidean space. What those examples show is that the link is not PL homeomorphic to a sphere.